# Is there any way to attach a database created in MS SQL Server 200808R2 to a SQL08 server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a database using a november CTP preview of MS SQL Server 2008R2. Is it possible to transfer this database to use with older version, SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Have you tried backing it up on the R2 SQL and restoring on the 2008?
Should work. I know 2008 to 2005 doesn't so maybe this is the same.

Comment: No, restoring didn't work. server 2008 showed message that his version is older then the version of server created backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can never downgrade by backup/restore or detach/attach

Your best bet is to use the wizard or an SSIS package

From [Paul Randall's myth series, item 24h](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-(2430)-twenty-six-restore-myths.aspx)

Comment: I managed to do it whrough import.export wizard and specifying instances using `tcp:ip/instanceName` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If backup/restore doesn't work, here's a couple of other ideas:

- BCP the data
- use replication to copy the data to a 2008 instance
- if the dataset isn't ridiculously large, write a script to do it